# Upload React Native app to Google Console [Expo Ejected]

Tags: android, react-native, expo, google-play-console

I had a expo app which I ejected, when following the eject instructions it generated some Android data for uploading to the play store (the following command was ran):

```
expo fetch:android:keystore
```

This gave the following:

- `xxxxxx.jsk` file
- `Keystore password`: xxxxxxx
- `Key alias`:         xxxxxxx
- `Key password`:      xxxxxxx

In the instructions on the react native website:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android#generating-an-upload-key

It says the following details are required in `gradle.properties`:

```
MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE=my-upload-key.keystore
MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS=my-key-alias
MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD=*****
MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD=*****
```

Are the details I have above used here? im slightly confused with the `.keystore` file as I have a `.jks` file.

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: @AmitRathee - just posted the answer below. .jks file works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.jks` file works fine, and the values provided when you run `expo fetch:android:keystore` will represent the correct values it asks for.